# How to use SSL with an asp-net-core application in a sub folder

Tags: angular, ssl, iis, asp.net-core

I have a couple applications. One is a angular-cli client application. The other is an AspNetCore WebApi application which serves data to my angular client. I have set up both as sub-applications(ie. hosted in IIS sub-folders using the add application feature of an existing website.

The configuration for the angular application was to build with a couple flags that would allow the app to work from a sub-folder.

```
ng build --deploy-url=/mock-v1/ --base-href=/mock-v1/
```

After building with these flags the application works fine under the client sub-application.

```
http://app/mock-v1/
```

Next, I build my AspNetCore appliction with the startup file configured as with the following changes.

```
// ConfigureServices
services.AddCors(c => c.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
    builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
    .AllowAnyMethod()
    .AllowAnyHeader()));

// Configure
app.UseStaticFiles("/data");
app.UsePathBase("/data");
```

After building and deploying this in IIS I can successfully visit my test page as follows with the sample output showing "["value1","value2"]":

```
http://app/data/api/values
```

Next, I setup a self hosted ssl certificate for my local domains as set in the hosts file:

```
PS C:\> New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName app, data -CertStoreLocation 
   "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

Locally here are the results:

```
http://app/mock-v1/            // works 
http://app/data/api/values     // works
https://app/mock-v1/           // doesn't work
https://app/data/api/values    // doesn't work
```

On Server where I have successfully setup SSL for the root domain:

```
http://[domain].com/mock-v1/            // works 
http://[domain].com/data/api/values     // doesn't work
https://[domain].com/mock-v1/           // works
https://[domain].com/data/api/values    // doesn't work
```

Actually, I don't know if the non-ssl version of the data/api/values works because it keeps on redirecting to https and nothing shows on the page.

If I setup the application as root websites for the following hosts file all the websites work.

```
app    127.0.0.1 
data   127.0.0.1

http://app/                // works 
http://data/api/values     // works
https://app/               // works 
https://data/api/values    // works
```

My ultimate goal is to get HTTPS to work on my sub applications. I am not interested in having multiple root domains for my deployment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 2.1 or 2.2 you can find how to set it up here. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio